# sharepoint 2013 signalr

Tags: signalr, sharepoint-2013

Following program is based on the idea given by following post:

http://spmatt.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/harnessing-signalr-in-sharepoint/

Since Sharepoint 2013 is based on .NET 4, no further configuration is required to use the SignlaR

library. I tried to use Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core version 1.0. The item added and item

edited event class was bind to the Project List. So whenever I created a new project item, it will

be automatically trigger the JavaScript in the web part as stated in the post stated above.

The item added event code is defined as follow:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
...
var connectionManager = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager;
var srContext = connectionManager.GetHubContext("messagehub");
srContext.Clients.Add.addMessage();
...
}
```

The messagehub class is defined as follow:

```
public class messagehub : Hub { 
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients
        Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    } 
}
```

The messagehub is saved in the same package. When I added a new item in the project list,

the itemadded event will be triggered. Error comes up at the GetHubContext statement that said

that messagehub could not be resolved.

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: I think you need to give more details than that. Does that project have the hub in its assembly? Also, you should be using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR (http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/11/11/microsoft-asp-net-signalr.aspx)

Comment: The program is based on the idea given by following post:

Comment: Is the hub class in the assembly that has the GetHubContext logic?

Comment: I'll be talking to Mat about adding a tutorial and updating the post for you. Stay tuned

Comment: Check out these two post working demos http://blog-aspc.azurewebsites.net/sharepoint-with-signalr/ http://melcher.it/2012/12/signalr-in-sharepoint-2013-the-real-time-web-is-coming/

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution + sourcecode on codeplex http://spsignalr.codeplex.com - there is a working example for an EventReceiver, too.

Comment: Here is a write up on how to do it in a SharePoint APP
http://spmatt.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/harnessing-signalr-in-sharepoint-2013-office-365/

Enjoy :)